# Add class name to element outside current container

Tags: javascript, css, attributes

How do I add a class name outside the current container, based on the `id` and/or the BS attribute?

Example code:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav-item is-active">
       <a href="#" data-bs-target="#nav-1">Lorem Ipsum</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" data-bs-target="#nav-2">Lorem Ipsum</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" data-bs-target="#nav-3">Lorem Ipsum</a>
     </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
     <div class="tab-pane" id="nav-1">
         <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </div>
     <div class="tab-pane" id="nav-2">
          <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </div>
     <div class="tab-pane" id="nav-3">
           <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

Take for example the first `li`. It has `is-active` class, its `a` has attribute `#nav-1`. I want to be able to add a class name `active` to `<div class="tab-pane">` with the `id="nav-1`. Is that possible?

Comment: What's your starting point? An event handler? What does "current" in "the current container" mean?

Comment: What do you mean by *"I want to be able to add a class name to `tab-pane` with the `id="nav-1`."*? The element with `id="nav-1"` **already** has the class `tab-pane` in your example HTML. Or do you mean you want to add a class to it? If so, what class?

Comment: Hi @T.J.Crowder, I'm sorry if it is confusing. What I meant to say is the current container which is `<ul>`. Then add a class name `active` outside of `<ul>` which is the `<div class="tab-pane">`Do I make sense?

Comment: Thanks. But again, what's your starting point? An event handler? Page load?

Comment: Are you trying to use [Bootstrap Collapse](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/collapse/)  ?

Comment: Okay, so I am using Bootstrap Tab and Splide JS. So on desktop, BS Tab is activated, on mobile Splide JS is activated. So the `is-active` class name on `<li>` is from SplideJS. It shows when I click the arrows. So I am thinking that the basis would be the `is-active` class when adding a class `active` to `<div class="tab-pane">`.

Comment: I recommand you to add these informations in your question to get answers that fit better your case. You could also add twitter-bootstrap and splidejs tags and [make a snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

In order for you to be able to click on any of the elements of a, you must first call the click event of that element in the form of $("a[data-bs-target|='#nav']").on('click', function(event){}) and then get the data-bs-target Attribute through this.getAttribute('data-bs-target') and get the value of each element and finally delete all the desired classes and That element added

```
    <style>
    .active {
    color: orange;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px solid orange;
}
</style>
<ul class="nav">
        <li class="nav-item is-active">
           <a href="#" data-bs-target="#nav-1">Lorem Ipsum</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" data-bs-target="#nav-2">Lorem Ipsum</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" data-bs-target="#nav-3">Lorem Ipsum</a>
         </li>
    </ul>
    
    <div class="tab-content">
         <div class="tab-pane" id="nav-1">
             <p>Lorem Ipsum 1</p>
         </div>
         <div class="tab-pane" id="nav-2">
              <p>Lorem Ipsum 2</p>
         </div>
         <div class="tab-pane" id="nav-3">
               <p>Lorem Ipsum 3</p>
         </div>
    </div>
<script>
            $("a[data-bs-target|='#nav']").on('click',function(event){
               event.preventDefault();
               var attributeValue = this.getAttribute('data-bs-target');
               $('.tab-pane').removeClass('active');
               $(attributeValue).addClass('active');
            });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var activeEl = document.querySelectorAll(".is-active")[0]; //Get active li element
var dataset = activeEl.querySelectorAll(":scope > a")[0].dataset; //Get data attributes from child a element
var div = document.getElementById(dataset.bsTarget.replace("#", "")); //Cut # from data-bs-target and get the tab-pane element by id

div.classList.add("mystyle"); //Add class
```

```css
.mystyle{
  background: #000000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav-item is-active">
       <a href="#" data-bs-target="#nav-1">Lorem Ipsum</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" data-bs-target="#nav-2">Lorem Ipsum</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" data-bs-target="#nav-3">Lorem Ipsum</a>
     </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
     <div class="tab-pane" id="nav-1">
         <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </div>
     <div class="tab-pane" id="nav-2">
          <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </div>
     <div class="tab-pane" id="nav-3">
           <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It would make your answer much more useful if you said *what* you did, *why*, and *how* it works. (Separately: You could use `querySelector` instead of having `querySelectorAll` build a `NodeList` just to use its first element. Also, you can use a single CSS query with a child combinator instead of multiple queries: `var dataset = document.querySelector(".is-active > a").dataset;`.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that you mean that at page load, you'd like to find the `a` element inside the `.nav-item` element with the class `is-active` and, using its `data-bs-target` attribute, add the `active` class to the `.tab-pane` that matches the selctor in `data-bs-target`.

If so, you can find the element by using `document.querySelector(".nav-item.is-active a")`, then take its `data-bs-target` attribute and, since that's a valid CSS selector, use it to find the relevant `tab-pane` element and add the class name.

```
const a = document.querySelector(".nav-item.is-active a");
const selector = a?.getAttribute("data-bs-target");
if (selector) {
   document.querySelector(selector)?.classList.add("active");
}
```

Notice the optional chaining (`?.`) there, so you don't get an error if there's no match for `.nav-item.is-active` or there's no match for the selector in its `data-bs-target` attribute.

Live Example:

```js
const a = document.querySelector(".nav-item.is-active a");
const selector = a?.getAttribute("data-bs-target");
console.log(selector);
if (selector) {
   document.querySelector(selector)?.classList.add("active");
}
```

```css
.active {
    color: orange;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav-item is-active">
       <a href="#" data-bs-target="#nav-1">Lorem Ipsum</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" data-bs-target="#nav-2">Lorem Ipsum</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" data-bs-target="#nav-3">Lorem Ipsum</a>
     </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
     <div class="tab-pane" id="nav-1">
         <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </div>
     <div class="tab-pane" id="nav-2">
          <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </div>
     <div class="tab-pane" id="nav-3">
           <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </div>
</div>
```